# How to nest a shared library into another shared library

Tags: c++, cmake

Is it feasible to wrap/nest a C++ .so library into another .so library so that a single .so library can be used instead of two .so libraries;
For e.g. if I have the source for A.so and A.so is using pre-compiled B.so, is it possible that A.so can be built in a way so that it contains the B.so and there is no need to link to B.so from the application that uses A.so

Comment: This might only work out-of-the-box if you have either the source of B, or a static library version of B.

Comment: You'll need to link the `B.a` file into `A.so`.